# filling in missing array indexes in php

Tags: php

Say I have an array like such:

`$chartData = array ( [00] => 1 [03] => 1 [09] => 1 [10] => 3 [11] => 1 [12] => 4 [13] => 2 [14] => 4 [15] => 6 [16] => 3 [17] => 5 [18] => 2 [20] => 1 [22] => 1 ) 1`

How can I fill in the missing indexes up until 24 (so 02, 04, 05, ect. until 24) with 0s?

Comment: is it a fixed count of 24?

Comment: What should be the last index?

Comment: Be very careful about numbers with leading zeroes; they're treated as octal by PHP, and `09` is invalid octal

Comment: the last index should be 24

Comment: And where are you stuck at doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function addkeyforArray(&$array)
{
    end($array);
    $maxcount = key($array); //Get the final key as max!
    for($i = 01; $i < $maxcount; $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($array[$i]))
        {
            $array[$i] = '';
        }
    }
}

addkeyforArray($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is a two-line loop.

```
for ($i = min($k=array_keys($chartData)); $i<=max($k); $i++) 
    $chartData[$i] = isset($chartData[$i]) ? $chartData[$i] : 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would get the list of keys, use the to create a list of *expected* keys and then do a diff on the array. As such

```
//Get the keys
$keys = array_keys($chartData);

//Convert them to integers for easier use
$keys = array_map(function ($key) {
    return (int) $key;
}, $keys);

//Get the last key
end($keys);
$lastKey = current($keys);

//Create the keys that we expect
$expectedKeys = range(0, $lastKey);

//Find out which keys are missing
$missingKeys = array_diff($expectedKeys, $keys);
```